# Difference between UseWhen and MapWhen in asp.net core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I know that if the predicate returns true then UseWhen will join the main branch after running the new branch whereas MapWhen won't join the main branch after running the new branch [theoretically].

But when I tried to purposefully call the next method from MapWhen, it actually merged back to the main branch.

```
private void HandleBranch(IApplicationBuilder app, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // Do work that doesn't write to the Response.
            logger.LogInformation("branch middleware before");
            // call the next component in the middleware pipeline
            await next.Invoke();
            // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
            logger.LogInformation("branch middleware after");
        });
    }
```

For eg, if I use the above method for both UseWhen and MapWhen then I am getting the same pipeline execution result ie.
if predicate is true then HandleBranch executes and then next middleware in pipeline. Ideally I was expecting the MapWhen to throw some an exception or just short circuit the pipeline on it's own.

I even tried going through github repo and microsoft docs for each of them but still not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Instead of your expectations what are you getting now could you share in a bit details?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron for me, both MapWhen and UseWhen are merging into the main branch

Comment: I doubt `await next.Invoke();` works here  instead of `await next();`. Would you kindly have a try with `await next();` Let me know your update.

Comment: I am afraid both are behaving similarly in this case ie they continue to merge with the main branch

Comment: Could please you share your `middleware` code here so that I can check

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is simple. make your method (HandleBranch) `private` to `public`.

For Call, the next middleware in the pipeline, use this:-

```
await next();
```

hope, it will resolve your issue.